# Errno 13 Permission Denied when reading file in python

Tags: python, nltk, readfile

my folder stemming contains 7 files and each file contains no. of document but my problem is permission denied.
I want to calculate the probability of each file which it is
probability of files = count of thatfile / number_of_docs

```
stemming = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona'
with open(stemming, "r", encoding="utf-8") as auto:
```

Comment: is this path a directory or a file ? `'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Akhbarona'`

Comment: directory @ChrisDoyle

Comment: `open()` is used to open file, not directory. If you want to open files in directory then first use `os.listdir(directory)` to get all filenames in this directory and later use `for`-loop to open every file separately - `open('/path/to/file')`